# New install displays errors and boots into cmd line

Tags: boot, system-installation, mount

I've got an old laptop which has vista on it (which is crap) so I've decided to move to ubuntu.

I don't have a CDROM or anything like that to mount the installation files on so I did it through windows (wubi.exe or something).

All was going well, it installed etc but upon rebooting I get to the loading screen in which it tells me there are serious errors.

Something like it can't mount / (root) and I think the disk drive as well.
How do I fix this?

Comment: If it can't mount the root partition this means Ubuntu won't start at all. So you have to fix this. I suspect there's something wrong with the ID's of the partitions. You'll have to repair /etc/fstab and figure out the correct ID's. It is probably easier and faster to borrow a CD and do a fresh install.

Comment: I've managed to find a CD and burned the installation file onto it. I've put it in the laptop and selected the CD from the boot menu but it just goes to a black screen with a flashing "|" for about 10 seconds and then proceeds to boot to windows. I've tested the CD out on my main computer which runs window 8.1 and I've managed to boot into the CD and I'm writing this from ubuntu.

Comment: So you're working with a so called live cd now. That is indeed possible but is usually not a long-term solution. Now it's probably time to find out why the laptop refuses to boot from the CD. Do you see anything else except than the flashing bar?

Comment: Nope, that's it. just the flashing bar on a black screen for about 10-20 seconds and then launches to windows.

Comment: What comes to mind is: are you sure it's a CD and not a DVD? If it boots on the desktop I don't see a reason why it doesn't on a laptop except that it is in a format that isn't recognized. So if your laptop has an (older) CD drive and you insert a DVD then it does not recognize the DVD and proceeds to boot from the hard drive.

Comment: It's a DVD sorry. It seems the laptop doesn't recognize the format or something as it just shows as "DVD RW Drive" instead of the "Install Ubuntu" that it is on my desktop.

Comment: Certain drives have a preference for DVD+ or DVD- and if it is the wrong type the DVDis not recognized.

Comment: Okay well this is the only DVD RW I have. Is there any other way I can install? I do have an external drive but have failed so far to get it to boot from it (not even UNetbootin works).

Comment: If you have an USB stick you can use it as install medium. Since you've your live cd that works on your desktop you can follow the procedure that is described here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick and then use the USB stick to install Ubuntu on your laptop.

Answer (score 0):

WUBI (Windows UBuntu Installer) is discontinued, and as such is not recommended for installing Ubuntu. You can use UNetbootin to make a bootable USB with Ubuntu. Grab UNetbootin from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/unetbootin/?source=recommended).

You can then install Ubuntu by following [this](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop).

Comment: John's answer works as well, but requires you have a Linux system available.

Answer (score 0):

Better than any graphical USB boot installers, i advice you to try this..

1. format the USB into FAT file system
2. open a terminal on Linux and run the following command

   ```
   dd if=/path/to/the/ubuntu.iso of=/dev/sd(USB disk partition number)
   ```
3. When it finishes, reboot your system.